# Access denied in IE (same domain!)

Tags: internet-explorer, frame, access-denied

I know about the cross-site-scripting problems with IE, but this is comming from the same server/domain. (I'm actually access the server with a IP adres... but I think that cannot be the problem?)

The thing is, I'm trying to translate a application with jquery.translate. In FF (surprise!) this is working like a charm. But in IE I get the dreaded 'Access Denied' error. This is the call I do:

```
$(top.frames["Content"].document).translate('english');
```

I'm doing this in the onload of the frame. And now for the really strange part: when I load the frameset for the first time *it works!* But when I click on links in the right-part of the frame, I get the error.
Even stranger: in the left part of the frame I've put a button, that will fire the *exact same code* - and then it works!

Of course, I thought that the event might fire too soon; before the right frame has finished loading. But even when I wait 10 seconds, after 10 seconds - boom, I get the error....

I'm running out of hair here.. :-)
Anybody got a clue?

thanks!

Paul

Comment: Are the frames referencing exactly the same domain or different subdomains, i.e., www.example.com and foo.example.com?

Comment: @tvanfosson: or even more plausible, www.example.com and example.com

Comment: He claims that he's using an IPAddress rather than a hostname, so that shouldn't explain the problem unless in one case he's using the IP and the other he's using a hostname.

Comment: @Eric - you might be onto something, perhaps the links on the right-side (where the problem occurs) are using the domain name not the IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error when trying to access functions in an iframe, both documents originating from the same domain. My technique for accessing the iframe's window object and it's functions was along these lines:

```
// if id for the iframe element is 'context', first make sure 
// it's accessible as a property of the main window object
if(! window.context ) window.context = window.frames[0] || null;
if( window.context === null ) alert("The Context screen is not available");

// grab a function from the iframe window and assign to var
var fadeLoader = window.context.fadeLoader; // this is an error in IE
```

...so before I even can try calling the function, I get an error for referencing it. Playing around in F12 console, here's what worked:

```
// grab a function from the iframe window and assign to var
var fadeLoader = window.context.window.fadeLoader; 
// now I can call the function
fadeLoader();
```

...but now, I get an error in Firefox because 'window' is not valid property of an iframe element in FF. Instead FF uses (correctly) contentWindow. So, to make this work all around:

```
if(! window.context ) window.context = window.frames[0] || null;
if(! window.context.window ) window.context.window = window.context.contentWindow;
var fadeLoader = window.context.window.fadeLoader;
fadeLoader();
```

Seems to work in IE, FireFox, Chrome and Safari.